# Can I measure the performance of a linux software bridge using this setup?

Tags: linux, networking, switch, bridge, software

I need to measure the performance of a linux network bridge (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_bridge) on a particular machine (`machine A`). My initial idea for a setup looked like this:

```
                              +-------------+
                              |  machine A  |
                              +-------------+
                              | eth0 | eth1 |
                              +-------------+
                                 ^       ^
+--------------+                 |       |               +--------------+
|   machine B  |<----------------+       +-------------->|   machine C  |
+--------------+                                         +--------------+
```

With `machine A` acting as the switch (bridging `eth0` and `eth1`), I'd measure the link between `machine B` and `machine C` using something like iperf. The trouble is, I don't have access to any suitable machines to play the roles of `machine B` and `machine C`. Someone suggested the following setup instead, using `machine A` as a stand-in for both (as it has more than enough physical interfaces):

```
                        +---------------------------+
                        |          machine A        |
                        +---------------------------+
                        | eth0 | eth1 | eth2 | eth3 |
                        +---------------------------+
                            ^      ^      ^      ^
                            |      |      |      |
                            +------+      +------+
```

this time bridging `eth1` and `eth2`, and then measuring the performance between `eth0` and `eth3`. To me, this seems a bit silly at first, but I can't say with certainty that it wouldn't work. My concern is that `machine A` would figure out that the traffic between `eth0` and `eth3` can be routed internally, bypassing the bridge and physical links.

Am I right or wrong, will this setup work?

Comment: Note: I posted this to network engineering first, but it was deemed off topic. I was suggested to post here.

Comment: Which connection speeds are we talking about?

Comment: The bridge is supposed to replace a single 100 Mbit link (all interfaces in the pic are 1 Gbps ). So anything near or above 100 Mbit is fine. But it would be interesting to see what speeds can be achieved. @Massimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you need to put those three instances in different network namespaces or different VRFs so they won't figure out the "shorter" path. Also you can check was the shorter path really taken by observing the counters on the bridge physical ports (and by looking at NIC LEDs — they usually blink when passing traffic).